# Appending a new line to a file in Python on Windows

Tags: python, newline

```
f = open(fn, 'ab')
f.write("\nline\n\ntest\n\ntest")
```

The file shows:

```
linetesttest
```

So all `\n` characters are ignored. I thought appending in binary mode ('ab') should enable correct `\n` behavior.

Using `\r\n` instead of `\n` works. I'm on Windows.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Don't open it in binary mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening it in binary mode is the problem. Don't use binary mode, and it'll do what you expect.